# Text alignment is off after being wrapped with Pressable

Tags: react-native

I am trying to include a clickable email within a body of text and I'm finding that when I wrap `<Text>` with `<Pressable>` the alignment of the link is higher than the rest of the sentence. Why is this and how can I fix this?

```
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <Text>
          This is the body of my text
          <Pressable onPress={() => Linking.openURL('info@company.com')}>
            <Text style={{color: 'blue}}> info@company.com</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </Text>
      </View>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{padding: 10}}>
    <Text style={{ alignVertical: 'center' }}>
        This is the body of my text
        <Pressable style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('info@company.com')}>
           <Text style={{color: 'blue}}> info@company.com</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: An answer without explanation is not constructive, please clearly describe what was wrong with the author implementation, and how your approach solves his/her problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the main Text tag separate. Text doesn't contain any other tags in it. so your code will be like as below:

```
<View style={{padding: 10, flexDirection:"row"}}> // Add flexDirection:"row"
  <Text>This is the body of my text </Text>
  <Pressable onPress={() => Linking.openURL('info@company.com')}>
    <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}> info@company.com</Text>
  </Pressable>
</View>
```

I hope this will work for you. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I ended up removing <Pressable> and using the onPress directly in the second <Text> component but the issue is that I still don't know why it did that with the Pressable